# How do I call java code from a Matlab program

Tags: java, matlab

I would like to calling my own Java program from Matlab.

This is my java program:

```
public class TestArgu{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test passing arguments!");
    }

    public void addNumber(int aNumber){
        ansNumber = aNumber+5;
        chk = aNumber;
        System.out.println("input number = " + chk + ".\n");
        System.out.println("ans = " + ansNumber + ".\n");
    }

    public int ansChk(){
        return ansNumber;
    }

    private int ansNumber;
    private int chk;
}
```

I did step by step from this link
http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-URS0E/?...1...

but it is not working with my program.
I'm running Matlab program from the Server computer. 
So I cannot edit the `classpath.txt`.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I always use this way [check it out](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/07/06/calling-java-from-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, delete the main function from your class. Then add the line

```
package mypackage.release;
```

before your class definition. Then compile it using the command

```
javac -verbose -cp /home/javaclasses -d /home/javaclasses /home/javasource/TestArgu.java
```

In matlab type

```
javaaddpath('/home/javaclasses');
clear java;
import mypackage.release.*;
test=TestArgu;
test.addNumber(6);
test.ansChk();
```

Remember that everytime you make changes and compile the java class, you must call `clear java` in matlab before the changes are available. This also has the unfortunate side effect of clearing all the variables in your workspace so make sure you don't have anything important to save before calling it.