# Can't import my java class into Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to import a custom Java class into matlab. I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069414/how-do-i-call-java-code-from-a-matlab-program) that I followed.

I have the following Java code

```
package mypackage.release;
public class TestArgu {
    public void addNumber(int aNumber){
        ansNumber = aNumber+5;
        chk = aNumber;
        System.out.println("input number = " + chk + ".\n");
        System.out.println("ans = " + ansNumber + ".\n");
    }

    public int ansChk(){
        return ansNumber;
    }

    private int ansNumber;
    private int chk;
}
```

Then I compile with

```
javac TestArgu.java
```

I make sure I add the folder that contains the `TestArgu.class` with `javaaddpath('.')` file and try to call it with matlab.

```
>> a = mypackage.release.TestArgu();
Undefined variable "mypackage" or class "mypackage.release.TestArgu".

>> import mypackage.release.*;
>> a = TestArgu();
Undefined function or variable 'TestArgu'.
>> a = mypackage.release.TestArgu.addNumber(1);
Undefined variable "mypackage" or class "mypackage.release.TestArgu.addNumber".
```

I'm using the same version of java to compile that matlab uses. (JDK 7, Matlab 2013b)

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Try it: > a = mypackage.release.TestArgu.addNumber(1);

Comment: Same thing, added it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same behaviour with the code above.  I think one problem is that there is no constructor for this class, so `a=TestArgu()` will fail.  I suggest doing the following.  Change the class definition by removing the `package my package.release` statement and adding a constructor to get

```
public class TestArgu {

        public TestArgu()
        {
            ansNumber = 0;
            chk       = 0;
        }  

        public void addNumber(int aNumber){
            ansNumber = aNumber+5;
            chk = aNumber;
            System.out.println("input number = " + chk + ".\n");
            System.out.println("ans = " + ansNumber + ".\n");
        }

        public int ansChk(){
            return ansNumber;
        }

        private int ansNumber;
        private int chk;
 }
```

Compile the code, as before

```
$ javac TestArgu.java
```

And then in MATLAB, add the path to wherever this compiled class exists

```
>> javaaddpath('/Users/geoff/Development/java'); % or wherever
```

Then instantiate the object

```
>> a = TestArgu

   a =
       TestArgu@2a307bb2
```

And try out the method

```
>> a.addNumber(37)
    input number = 37.

    ans = 42.
```